# If $(a^5-a^3+3)(b^5-b^3+3)(c^5-c^3+3)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2 \quad$ Prove that $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, integral-inequality

If $$(a^5-a^3+3)(b^5-b^3+3)(c^5-c^3+3)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2 \quad a\ge b\ge c. $$ Prove that $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$.

here is my attempt
$$a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$$ 
is equivalent to $$(a^3-1)(a^1-1)\ge 0$$
or $a\ge -1$
so by their symmety
$a,b,c\ge -1$

obviously,$a,b,c=-1or 1$,when it take the equal sign

so how to construct inequalities which satisfies conditions above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rce2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is wrong. Try $(a,b,c)=(-2,-2,1)$.

If $a\geq-1$ then $a^5-a^3\geq a^2-1$ because it's $(a-1)^2(a+1)(a^2+a+1)\geq0$, which is obvious.

If you need to prove that
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^5-a^3+3)\geq3(a+b+c)^2$$
for all $\{a,b,c\}\subset[-1,+\infty)$ then $a^5-a^3+3\geq a^2+2$ and similar and see my solution here:

[Prove that $(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\geq 3(a+b+c)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602810/)

Comment: if$ a,b,c\ge 0$,then how to do it

Comment: @lurk lurk vice account I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: so how to prove that $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$ if $a,b,c\ge -1$

Comment: @lurk lurk vice account See the second line of my solution. I fixed something.

Comment: if  $a\ge b\ge c$ then how

Comment: @lurk lurk vice account Can you say a full statement?

Comment: I am trying to find the missing condition

Comment: @lurk lurk vice account Where did you take this problem?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rce2.png

Comment: @lurk lurk vice account Can you write in Chines without pictures? I'll can use the google-translate.

Comment: the second line in the picture is " 证明（xxx数学工作室） " ，words in brackets is the source of the question .As you said above ,it is wrong ,so I guess it lacks some conditions (like $a\ge b\ge c$ )

Answer (score 0):

After you deduced the following: $$\prod_{a,b,c}(a^5-a^3+3)\geq\prod_{a,b,c}(a^2+2),$$
the rest is duplicate of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602810/prove-that-a22b22c22-geq-3abc2/1602823)

Answer (score 0):

@dezdichado But the question you cite is based on $a,b,c\ge 0$

here $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$

and you may confuse the conditions and conclusions

Comment: that's because it suffices to assume that. use $a^2 = (-a)^2.$ and $a+b+c\leq |a|+|b|+|c|.$

Comment: by using $\left(a^2+2\right)\left(b^2+2\right)\left(c^2+2\right) \ge 3\left(a^2+b^2+1\right)$  ,how to prove  $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$  @dezdichado